# Use a symbol in a node as anchor

Tags: nodes, forest, trees

Is it possible to use a symbol in a node as an anchor?
I want to draw lines from the `\circ` symbol in a parent to the childs.
I want to do something like `for tree={parent anchor=\circ, child anchor=north}` (this does of course not work).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\section{Default}

\begin{forest}
[$\varphi \lor (\psi \land \chi) \circ (\varphi \lor \psi) \land (\varphi \lor \chi)$
  [$\varphi \circ (\varphi \lor \psi) \land (\varphi \lor \chi)$
    [$\varphi \circ \varphi \lor \psi$
    [$\varphi \circ \varphi {,} \psi$
    [*]           
    ]           
    ]
    [$\varphi \circ \varphi \lor \chi$
    [$\varphi \circ \varphi {,} \chi$
    [*]           
    ]               
    ]
  ]
  [$\psi \land \chi \circ (\varphi \lor \psi) \land (\varphi \lor \chi)$
  [$\psi {,} \chi \circ (\varphi \lor \psi) \land (\varphi \lor \chi)$
    [$\psi {,} \chi \circ \varphi \lor \psi$
    [$\psi {,} \chi \circ \varphi {,} \psi$
    [*]           
    ]             
    ]
    [$\psi {,} \chi \circ \varphi \lor \chi$
    [$\psi {,} \chi \circ \varphi {,} \chi$
    [*]           
    ]                 
    ]           
  ]
  ]     
]
\end{forest}

\section{Now with anchors}

\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north}
[$\varphi \lor (\psi \land \chi) \circ (\varphi \lor \psi) \land (\varphi \lor \chi)$
  [$\varphi \circ (\varphi \lor \psi) \land (\varphi \lor \chi)$
    [$\varphi \circ \varphi \lor \psi$
    [$\varphi \circ \varphi {,} \psi$
    [*]           
    ]           
    ]
    [$\varphi \circ \varphi \lor \chi$
    [$\varphi \circ \varphi {,} \chi$
    [*]           
    ]               
    ]
  ]
  [$\psi \land \chi \circ (\varphi \lor \psi) \land (\varphi \lor \chi)$
  [$\psi {,} \chi \circ (\varphi \lor \psi) \land (\varphi \lor \chi)$
    [$\psi {,} \chi \circ \varphi \lor \psi$
    [$\psi {,} \chi \circ \varphi {,} \psi$
    [*]           
    ]             
    ]
    [$\psi {,} \chi \circ \varphi \lor \chi$
    [$\psi {,} \chi \circ \varphi {,} \chi$
    [*]           
    ]                 
    ]           
  ]
  ]     
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You cannot do this. You could fake it. But it would be easier to fake it by splitting nodes than by adjusting alignments, I think. There are some similar examples on the site already: probably you could use one of the strategies from there.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for your comment. I'm just starting to use tikz and forest, can you provide a link to "splitting nodes" that is easy to follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the general idea. No doubt requires some tweaking.

The node content is entered as `<left part> : <right part>`. The colon will be replaced by `\circ` during processing. The left and right parts will be split out to create new nodes to the left and right of the `\circ`. Nodes containing `*` are not touched. A `phantom` root is added as the root cannot have siblings.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  declare toks={left bit}{},
  declare toks={right bit}{},
  my anchors/.style={
    delay={
      for root={
        replace by={[, phantom, append]}
      },
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      where={
        > O+tt= On=! & {content}{*} {level}{0}
      }{}{
        split option={content}{:}{left bit, right bit},
        delay={
          insert before/.process={
            Ow {left bit}{{[##1, math content, no edge]} }
          },
          insert after/.process={
            Ow {right bit}{{[##1, math content, no edge]}}
          },
          content=\circ,
          text height=\circht,
          text depth=\circdp,
          child anchor=parent,
          parent anchor=children,
          inner xsep=-100pt,
          math content,
        }
      }
    },
    before packing={
      where={
        > Ow+P {n children}{isodd(##1)}
      }{
        calign child/.process={Ow+n{n children}{(##1+1)/2}},
        calign=child edge,
      }{}
    }
  }
}
\newlength\circht
\settoheight{\circht}{$()\varphi$}
\newlength\circdp
\settodepth{\circdp}{$()\varphi$}
\begin{document}


\begin{forest}
  my anchors
  [\varphi \lor (\psi \land \chi) : (\varphi \lor \psi) \land (\varphi \lor \chi)
    [\varphi : (\varphi \lor \psi) \land (\varphi \lor \chi)
      [\varphi : \varphi \lor \psi
      [\varphi : \varphi {,} \psi
      [*]           
      ]           
      ]
      [\varphi : \varphi \lor \chi
      [\varphi : \varphi {,} \chi
      [*]           
      ]               
      ]
    ]
    [\psi \land \chi : (\varphi \lor \psi) \land (\varphi \lor \chi)
    [\psi {,} \chi : (\varphi \lor \psi) \land (\varphi \lor \chi)
      [\psi {,} \chi : \varphi \lor \psi
      [\psi {,} \chi : \varphi {,} \psi
      [*]           
      ]             
      ]
      [\psi {,} \chi : \varphi \lor \chi
      [\psi {,} \chi : \varphi {,} \chi
      [*]           
      ]                 
      ]           
    ]
    ]     
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: tree with split nodes]